# Black-Scholes SDE solution help

Tags: integration, normal-distribution, finance, stochastic-differential-equations

I am trying to solve the Black Scholes SDE, but got really stuck.
I have done most of the derivation but the integral seem intractable to me. The integrals look bit like the Normal Distributions PDF, but I am not sure how I am supposed to solve it. Could anyone help me with what method to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. Try doing a change of variables in the exponential part of the integral. Make it so that you get "$e^{-\frac{1}{2} x^2}$". Then you can relate this to the cdf of the normal distribution, ie
$$ \Phi(z) = \int_{-\infty}^z \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{1}{2} y^2} dy. $$
Note also that, since the integrand is a pdf,
$$ 1 - \Phi(z) = \int_z^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{1}{2} y^2} dy. $$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Would you be able to suggest what substitution to use? I think from there it should be fairly straightforward.

Comment: I'm on my phone now (it's bed time in the UK!), so can't TeX, but basically in the first let $u$ be the thing in square brackets for the first integral, and $v$ the corresponding for the second. Then identify 'z' in each case, hopefully as the same thing as the answer you found!